# subtracting one image from another

Tags: matlab, image-processing

how can i subtract one image from another either row wise or column wise ?

Answer (score 3):

I don't quite understand what you mean with 'row-wise' or 'column-wise'. In MATLAB, you can subtract two images from one another directly, as long as they're the same size, of course.

```
%# load the images
im1 = imread('firstImage.tif')
im2 = imread('secondImage.tif')

%# subtract
deltaImage = im1 - im2;
```

Note: If you have the image processing toolbox, you can use `deltaImage = imsubtract(im1,im2)` to deal with underflow if your images are integer arrays.

Comment: i mean to say that i want to subtract from the pixel wise either from row wise or column wise and to get the difference

Comment: Since you don't need to loop in order to subtract images, there is no need to worry about rows/cols.

Answer (score 0):

Use OpenCV Have two IPlImage variables point to your two images and subtract them..like this

```
IplImage im1=your image1;
IplImage im2=your image2;
IplImage im3;
cvSub(im1,im2,im3);
```

Obviously you need to open the images first. This works because iplimage is a derived structure from mat

Comment: thanks for the answer but i neeed in matlab if you dont mind giving me in matlab

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution:

```
[file path]=uigetfile('*.jpg');
I=imread([path file]);
[file path]=uigetfile('*.jpg');
J=imread([path file]);
K=I-J;
figure;
imshow(K);
title('SUBTRACTED IMAGE ');
```